# Field extension, primitive root of unity solvable by radicals

Tags: galois-theory

I'm stuck with this exercise.

I'd like to show, that for a field $K$ with $\mathrm{char}(K)=0$ and $\omega_n$ being a primitive n-th root of unity $K(\omega_n)/K$ is solvable.

I thought I could do induction by n, but I didn't get that far with that.

Comment: One says field extensions are solvable, not "solvable by radicals." We say *equations* are solvable by radicals. Can you not figure out the Galois group of the extension? Also, were you trying to say something about ${\rm char}(K)$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the characteristic. OK, the Galois group should be $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Should be $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$, actually. Abelian implies solvable. So the extension is solvable. You didn't remove "by radicals" from your question. Are we really talking about the field extension (and hence its Galois group), or an equation you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Isn't it by definition that this is a radical extension?

Comment: Yes, of course it should be $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^x$ (I always press enter -.-). I mean the field extension. I will edit it now.